# Is it possible to run cy.writeFile or cy.readFile commands as part of a cy.route action?

Tags: javascript, promise, routes, cypress

I am currently attempting to mock up a client server response pattern using Cypress.

I would like to:

1. Use cy.route to catch a call to set data when I click a "save" button
2. Write the response to a file using the onResponse parameter of my cy.route
3. Use the contents of the file as my response for the same cy.route call

Currently, if I include either a cy.writeFile, or even a console.log(cy.readFile(testFile))  command, I get an error when I call the route with a cy.wait.

Error:

```
application_actions.js:84 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusText' of undefined
```

If I remove the cy.writeFile or readFile from my onResponse block the code executes fine.

Here's an example of what I am doing:

```
beforeEach(() => {
      //call fixture file 
      cy.fixture('newApplication.json').as('newApplication')
      cy.server()
      //This first route is used when I load a page that contains application data. 
      //This works fine
      cy.route('GET', 'applications/*', '@newApplication').as('getNewApplication')
      //This route is hit when I click a Save Button to save updates to my application data
      cy.route({
        method: 'PATCH', 
        url: 'applications/update/*',
        onRequest: (xhr) => {
          cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/newApplication.json', xhr.request.body.application)
          },
        response: '@newApplication'
      })
      .as('updatedApplication')
      cy.visit('/admin/review_application/1')
      cy.wait('@getNewApplication')
      .its('response.headers')
      .its('content-type')
      .should('contain','application/json')
    });

it.only('Saving Restaurant Name changes page header text', () => {
      //Alter some application data
      cy.get('#Restaurant\\ Name')
        .clear()
        .type('Header Update Test');
      cy.get('#name-buttons\\ Accept').click();
      //Click save button to save data change
      clickSaveButton();
      //hit updatedApplication route when data is saved
      cy.wait('@updatedApplication').should('have.property','status',200)
      //Test fails on above wait every time
      cy.reload();
      cy.wait('@getNewApplication')
      cy.get('#Restaurant\\ Name').then($newText => {
          //compare text values to ensure the data change was saved
          cy.get('.MuiTypography-h2').then($headerText => {
          expect($headerText).to.have.text($newText.prop('value'));
        });
      });
```

It seems like cy.route is completely synchronous, so maybe this isn't possible, or maybe I am doing something wrong.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right way, just updating the second call too earlier. I would like to suggest you to try something like:

1. Remove your route update from your `beforeEach` block
2. Use the `cy.wait`, and add it **after** your click action, like:

```js
cy.wait('@getNewApplication').then((xhr) => {
  cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/newApplication.json', xhr.request.body.application)
  cy.route({
   method: 'PATCH',
   url: 'applications/update/*',
   response: '@getNewApplication'
 }).as('updatedApplication');
})
```

Worked fine for me in my project.

*Tip: If it works, you can extract the update to a method, to a better readability.*

Comment: This seems close, but the call would be:

`cy.wait('@updatedApplication').then((xhr) => {
  cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/newApplication.json', xhr.request.body.application)
  cy.route({
   method: 'PATCH',
   url: 'applications/update/*',
   response: '@getNewApplication'
 }).as('updatedApplication');
})`

which isn't working, since I am defining updateApplication after I am waiting for it. I think this in on the right track, though

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get cypress to write to the same fixture file, then read back altered data. Even if I added a second cy.fixure call to try to pull in the modified file.

Instead, I ended up writing to a new file, then setting up new routes to read it.

`clickSaveButton();
      cy.wait('@updatedApplication').then((xhr) => {
        cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/updatedApplication.json', xhr.request.body.application).then(() => {
          cy.fixture('updatedApplication.json').as('updatedApplication')
          cy.route('GET', 'applications/*', '@updatedApplication').as('getUpdatedApplication')
        })
      })
      cy.reload()
      cy.wait('@getUpdatedApplication')`

Thanks for helping get me here!